# evaluate list to Object attributes in python / django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just started with python and django and looking for a possibility to iterate through an objects attribute, to realize a search function over all fields.

The diff object classes an inheriting from an abstract base class and I created a static function searchable which should give the attributes back which could be searched through.

```
class Item(BaseItem):
    internal_ean = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    @staticmethod
    def searchable():
        return ['ean', 'internal_ean', 'brand', 'model']
```

No I want to do something like that:

```
for key in Item.searchable():
    try:
        string='{}={}'.format(key,term)
        my_list.extend(getattr(Item.objects, "filter")(string))
    except (Item.DoesNotExist):
        pass
```

What can I do to avoid eval and stuff like that? Is there a way to return a pointer or a list of attributes I can use directly?

From django I get back:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search_items_and_exact(term):
    """Returns items with all searchable attributes exactly equals to term"""
    filters = {}
    for search_attr in Item.searchable():
        filters[search_attr] = term
    return Item.objects.filter(**filters)


def search_items_or_exact(term):
    """Returns items with any searchable attributes exactly equals to term"""
    q_seq = Q()
    for search_attr in Item.searchable():
        filters = {search_attr: term}
        q_seq = q_seq | Q(**filters)
    return Item.objects.filter(q_seq)

def search_items_and_contains(term, ignore_case=False):
    """Returns items with all searchable attributes contains term"""
    if ignore_case:
        contains = 'icontains'
    else:
        contains = 'contains'
    filters = {}
    for search_attr in Item.searchable():
        filters["{0}__{1}".format(search_attr, contains)] = term
    return Item.objects.filter(**filters)

def search_items_or_contains(term, ignore_case=False):
    """Returns items with any searchable attributes contains term"""
    if ignore_case:
        contains = 'icontains'
    else:
        contains = 'contains'
    q_seq = Q()
    for search_attr in Item.searchable():
        filters = {"{0}__{1}".format(search_attr, contains): term}
        q_seq = q_seq | Q(**filters)
    return Item.objects.filter(q_seq)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
qdict = dict.fromkeys(Item.searchable(), term)
rquery = Item.objects.filter(**qdict)
```

Comment: oh wow! thats easy ... I still need to learn a lot from python :) Thanks!